# Trying to add a string to an arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Why is the follow array assignment not working...

working part....

```
String[] values = new String[] { "Android","BlackBerry","HardCore"};
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) 
   {
      list.add(values[i]);
   }
```

not working part...whit I add the following code to that onclick of a button the app crashes
can anyone help...my ultimate goal is to get the text from a edittext view from the screen and place in into the list...however I and trying to do the following first

```
public void onClick(View view) 
   {
   list.add(new String("testing"));                 
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
```

Comment: Welcome To StackOverflow. Are you getting any exception? If so, post the stacktrace.

Comment: I would recommend not to use an ArrayList because it is not typecasted... The generic supporting alternative would be List

Comment: How does ArrayList<String> even compile? ArrayList has no type parameters. Did you mean List<String>?

Comment: sorry now started android..how do one "post the stacktrace"?

Answer (score 1):

Is `onClick()` supposed to be an event handler for a button click? If so, the signature is wrong.

I believe you are looking for something like this. I have changed it from an ArrayList to a generic List. And initialized it with a collection initializer, and made it accessible from within your function. Please run the code below and let us know if you get exceptions.

```
List<string> MyList=new List<string>() {"Android", "Blackberry", "Hardcore"};

public void onClick(View view)
   {
   MyList.Add("testing");
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
```

Comment: Design error with the Lst<string>....saying "Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)"

Comment: @user3103307 Are you programming in Java, or in C#? And make sure you check what your post for typos, to reduce confusion.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();` can this sentence be compile successfully? it cause compiling error in my VS2010 and .NetFramework3.5. I think you could use `List<string> list = new List<string>();` to replace it.

Comment: Design time error saying "Cannot instantiate the type List<R.string>" at the List<string>....